# customising a model field for serialization

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I am doing a project on django. I have a model EmployeeProfile with several fields along with a field education with following data - (institute, year, course, description).
in model i am storing data in form of a deliminated field.
e.g. a sample value for education - " XYZ colllege | 1994 | Btech | blabla "

But i want to serialize it along with other fields in the dict form i.e.

```
{ education:{ year: '1994', course: ' Btech', college: ' XYZ ', description: 'blabla'}}
```

and in future i would also liked to use it as an array deliminated by ';'
but that's not necessarily needed now.

I am new to django restframework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can split the education field value by using split.
Then you can serialize it accordingly.

```
class CustomModel:
    def __init__(self, year,course,college,description):
        self.year = year
        self.course = course
        self.description = description
        self.college = college

class CustomSerializer(NonNullSerializer):

    year = serializers.IntegerField()
    course = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()
    college = serializers.CharField()
```

Add this in view.py

```
    education_value = ...
    year,course,college,description = education_value.split('|')
    education_obj = CustomModel(year=year,course=course,college=college,description=description)
    serialized_data = CustomSerializer(education_obj)
    return serialized_data.data
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It is good.
However i have a doubt. will above CustomModel class will also be saved as a table in database or it is just for help to make easy serialization?

And if i want to use CustomSerializer class in some other model serializer, then i have to make it nested right?

Comment: It is just to make serialisation easy , and will not be created as a database table.It is just a class, to make a particular kind of object as for input for a serialiser, here  CustomSerializer.
Db tables are only created when you inherit class models.Model.
I didn't quite get the last part of the question.

Comment: I meant suppose i have a model 'Profile' and it has the field education value. now if i will serialize it using List or Detail view serial, how to include this custom Serializer in that , so that it does not take original education value representation but the above custom representation.

Comment: It can be used by the code in views.py , assigning the serializer explicitly to education_value.
Also you can not use it in model serializer but can be used as a field  in serializer.Serializer class.  Serializer Code :::  class ProfileSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
        education = CustomSerializer()
similarly for other fields.